# Algebra question to find all ordered pairs to a set of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, symmetry, symmetric-polynomials

Find all ordered pairs of real numbers ($x,y$) for which
$$(1+x)(1+x^{2})(1+x^{4})=1+y^{7}$$
$$(1+y)(1+y^{2})(1+y^{4})=1+x^{7}$$
I am not sure on how to solve this. There is a clear symmetry in the problem. Also on expanding the LHS, we will get the GP
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7=1+y^7$$ and similarly for the second equation. I tried manipulating the two equations and factorise them but I was unsuccesful. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: This 7th degree polynomial in the LHS can be written $\frac{x^8-1}{x-1}$. Do you know why ?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you with my (now deleted) answer Pravimish, I didn't realize it was wrong until CalvinLin corrected me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that

- If $ x = y$, then we have the solutions $ (0, 0), (-1, -1)$.
- We will show that there are no solutions with $ x \neq y$.
- If $ x = 0$, then from the first equation $ y = 0$.
- If $ x > 0, y < 0 $ then $ 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^7 > 1 > 1 + y^7 $, so no solutions. Likewise for $ x < 0, y > 0$.
- If $x, y > 0$ then notice for for real $x$, $ (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4) > 1 + x^7$. Hence, we have $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4) = 1 + y^7 <  (1+y)(1+y^2)(1+y^4 ) = 1 + x^7 $ which is a contradiction.
- If $ x , y  < 0$, then multiplying the first equation by $ 1 - x \neq 0$ and the second by $ 1 - y \neq 0$, and subtracting the two, we get

$$ y^ 8 - x^8 = (y - x) + (y^ 7 - x^7) + xy (x^6 - y^6)$$

$\qquad$ If $x < y < 0 $, then the LHS is negative, but each term on the RHS is positive. Hence contradiction.   Likewise if $ y < x < 0 $.

---

Note: A very common misconception when solving symmetric system of equations is thinking that all solutions to $x = f(y), y = f(x)$ are of the form $ y = x$.
In fact, what we truly require is $ f(f(x)) = x, y = f(x)$.
This is most obvious when looking at self-inverse functions like $f(x) = x, f(x) = -x, f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. However, it's not about the function, but about the "self-inverse" point, namely $f(x) = f^{-1} (x)$.

Comment: If we had the simultaneous equations $f(x)=g(y)$ and $f(y)=g(x)$ (assuming the solution set is finite) where $f$ and $g$ are both polynomial functions then is it true to say that the only solutions to the equations can occur when $y=x$ or $y=-x$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Not at all. Setting $ h = g^{-1} \circ f $ (assuming $ g^{-1}$ exists), we have $ h(x) = y, h(y) = x$, which as you now know, could have solutions other than $ y = \pm x$.

Answer (score 3):

Since we have powerful graphing calculators, let's see what Desmos tells us

[image]

OK, we have some clues, don't we? The first curve seems to lie above the line $y=x$ for $x<-1$ and for $x>0$; for $-1<x<0$ it lies below. But the second curve is the symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$.

Now let's prove the statement above rigorously. Let's try and see where
$$
\sqrt[7]{x+x^2+x^3+x^5+x^5+x^6+x^7}>x
$$
This becomes
$$
x(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)>0
$$
and, factoring,
$$
x(x+1)(x^4+x^2+1)>0
$$
hence this holds for $x<-1$ or $x>0$.

Thus, using the symmetry, the curves described by the two equations are always in the opposite half-planes defined by $y=x$. Hence they can only intersect on $y=x$.

Comment: @CalvinLin I added the graph, which suggests the following proof.

Comment: +1 Ah, I see what you're doing now. The introductory paragraph provides context for the rest of what you did.